# VMWare shared folders not working, vmware-tools issue?

Tags: vmware, shared-folders

I'm having trouble getting VMWare to enable shared folders between the host and vm as every time I try to enable it, I get the following error dialog:

```
VMWare Player
Unable to update run-time folder sharing status: Unknown error.
```

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 on the VM. I've read that it is likely a VMWare Tools issue, but I've reinstalled countless times now as root, guest, my account, and still no luck. I ensured that I had done `apt-get` on the prerequisites of gcc, build-essentials and such, but still to no avail. A couple of times after reinstalling VMWareTools the error dialog did not appear, but even when a shared folder was added it did not appear in the `/mnt/hgfs/` directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to potential causes/solutions.

Answer (score 4):

System Info:

> Windows 8 x64 Host, Ubuntu 13.04 Guest VMware Workstation 9.0

I faced the same problem here but following code helped me get the shared folders from host:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

Just keep on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> for all defaults and then do this at the terminal

```
mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /home/user1/shares
```

here `user1` is your username and `shares` is where your shared folders would be displayed. If this doesn't work try omitting `shares` from above command.

Comment: Good advice! One small thing: you need to create the /home/user1/shares directory first.

Comment: I get an error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device

Comment: i get an error: Could not add entry to mtab, continuing

Comment: facing thid Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device