# Cannot see shared folder in /mnt/hgfs

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, lubuntu, vmware

I am trying to share a folder between **Lubuntu 13.04** (in VMware player) and Windows 7 64 bit. I followed a tutorial till step 16. I typed a command and saw nothing. I also went into the /mnt/hgfs folder and saw nothing there. How do I fix this ?

http://theholmesoffice.com/how-to-share-folders-between-windows-and-ubuntu-using-vmware-player/

Command -

```
dir /mnt/hgfs
```

---

EXTRAS -

By the way, this is how I actually reached step 16.

Step 12 - `sudo apt-get install hgfsclient`
Step 14 - If it does not work, then follow this tutorial - http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/03/how-to-quickly-install-vmware-tools-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/
Step 16 - STUCK !!!

Comment: you are using virtualbox ? and i think thats not the popular way to access /create shared folder and probably not the easiest wait i am writing answer try that one

Comment: And please make sure that you have guest addition installed on your virtual machine

Comment: @YousafEhsan - vmware player and not virtualbox. I don't want to reinstall everything into vbox. Anyway, it was crashing too often. Player is better.

Answer (score 2):

**Install VM-Ware Tools on Linux**

```
sudo apt-get -y install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse && reboot
```

**This command mounts any files that are shared from the host into /mnt/hgfs**

```
sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

Following from this answer to a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/a/290528, I installed open-vm-tools just before step 16. Once that was done, I was able to complete step 16 successfully and continue on my way.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

I did not need to use the mount command as suggested in the linked answer.

Comment: thanks for your response. this post was so long ago. I completely forgot about it. I don't have that problem anymore. So, i cannot try your answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is install `open-vm-tools`
And use `mount` command if it wouldn't mount automatically.
( also you can put the mount path in `/etc/fstab` for mounting auto with your specific options )`mount source destination`